# Passing only one argument with CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation (x,y)

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, animation

I have multiple animations on a button, and I'm using CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation to do this.

Is it possible to use only one argument with it, only "x" or only "y"?

I've tried everything but couldn't make it work:

```
 button.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(nil, 10);

 button.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(NULL, 10);

 etc, etc...
```

Or make it the "x" the current location. If I use 0 it will bring the button to the original location.

Is it possible to do this?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Pass 0. A translation of 0 along an axis produces no change, because 0 is the identity of addition (which is what translation is).

```
button.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, someYValue);
```

Comment: The problem is that if I pass zero it goes back to the original location. I have multiple animations on the same image, so if it keeps bringing the image to the original location if I only want to change the x or the y.

Comment: @tomDev: I don't think animations stack like that. They just set the property directly.

Answer (score 0):

Translation in x direction only:

```
CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(x, 0.0);
```

Translation in y direction only:

```
CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, y);
```

Answer (score 0):

`CGAffineTransformTranslate` retains the previous transform.
You can therefore call `CGAffineTransformTranslate(myview.transform,0,y)` or whatever suits you.

```
CGAffineTransform CGAffineTransformTranslate (
   CGAffineTransform t,
   CGFloat tx,
   CGFloat ty
);
```